# Differentiating between an imported package and one run at the CLI when using Entrypoints in Python

Tags: python, entry-point

I have a python package that most commonly used as a CLI tool, but I sometimes run it as a library for my own purposes. (e.g. turning it into a web-app or for unit testing)

For example, I'd like to `sys.exit(1)` on error to give the end-user a nice error message on exception when used as a CLI command, but `raise` an Exception when it's used as an imported library.

I am using an `entry_points` in my `setup.py`:

```
entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'jello=jello.cli:main'
        ]
    }
```

This works great, but I can't easily differentiate when the package is run at the CLI or it was imported because `__name__` is always `jello.cli`. This is because the Entrypoint is basically importing the package as normal.

I tried creating a `__main__.py` file and pointing my Entrypoint there, but that did not seem to make a difference.

I'm considering checking `sys.argv[0]` to see if my program name exists there, but that seems to be a brittle hack. (in case the user aliases the command or something) Any other ideas or am I just doing it wrong? For now I have been passing an `as_lib` argument to my functions so they will behave differently based on whether they are loaded as a module or run from the CLI, but I'd like to get away from that.

Comment: You should attempt to differentiate between the importable/library parts of your codebase and the CLI. The CLI should use your library and the library should raise exceptions that are specifically handled by the entrypoint.

Comment: If I understand you correctly it sounds like I should refactor my code such that the functions that do stuff raise exceptions, but the `main()` function should be dedicated to CLI functionality. That way I can `try/except` within `main()` and provide nice error messages there instead of doing it within the called function. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minimal example of a package structure that can be used as a `cli` and a library simultaneously.

This is the directory structure:

```
egpkg/
├── setup.py
└── egpkg/
   ├── __init__.py
   ├── lib.py
   └── cli.py
```

This is the `entry_points` in `setup.py`. It's identical to yours:

```py
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "egpkg_cli=egpkg.cli:main",
        ],
    },
```

`__init__.py`:

```py
from .lib import func
```

`cli.py`
This is where you will define your CLI and handle any issues that your functions, that you define in other python files, raise.

```py
import sys
import argparse

from egpkg import func


def main():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument("a", type=int)
    args = vars(p.parse_args())

    try:
        result = func(**args)
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit(str(e))

    print(f"Got result: {result}", file=sys.stdout)
```

`lib.py`
This is where the core of your library is defined, and you should use the library how you would expect your users to use it. When you get values/input that won't work you can [`raise`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) it.

```py
def func(a):
    if a == 0:
        raise ValueError("Supplied value can't be 0")
    return 10 / a
```

---

Then from in the python console or a script you can:

```py
In [1]: from egpkg import func
In [2]: func(2)
Out[2]: 5.0
In [3]: func(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/egpkg/egpkg/lib.py", line 3, in func
    raise ValueError("Supplied value can't be 0")
ValueError: Supplied value can't be 0

Supplied value can't be 0
```

And from the CLI:

```sh
(venv) ~ egpkg_cli 2
Got result: 5.0
(venv) ~ egpkg_cli 0
Supplied value can't be 0
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I needed to do. Not sure why I didn't think of it myself. :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is called a 'main guard' in Python. The module knows its name at any given time. If the module is executed from the CLI, its name is `__main__`. So, what you can do is put all functionality you want in some function at the module level, and then you can call it differently from within the 'main guard' from how you'd call it as a library. Here's what a 'main guard' looks like:

```python
def myfunc(thing, stuff):
   if not stuff:
      raise MyExc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
       myfunc(x, y)
    except MyExc:
       sys.exit(1)
```

Here, the sys.exit is only called on error if the module is executed from the command line as a script.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in the case of using Entrypoints because the user is not directly running the file as a script, but the Entrypoint is importing the module. This means the module will always have its real name and will not see itself as `__main__`.